# Can't access JSON data from Weather API

Tags: swift, api

```
class WeatherData {
    private let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    private let urlPathBase = "https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=efcc8b6300354517b08194421202604&format=json&q="

    private var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask? = nil

    var delegate:WeatherDataProtocol? = nil

    init(){}

    func getData(exampleDataNumber: String){

        var urlPath = self.urlPathBase
        urlPath = urlPath + exampleDataNumber

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        print(url!)

        let dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    if jsonResult != nil {
                        print(jsonResult)
                        let temperature_c = jsonResult?.value(forKeyPath: "data.current_condition.temp_C") as Any

                        if temperature_c != nil {
                            self.delegate?.responseDataHandler(data: jsonResult!)
                        } else {
                            self.delegate?.responseError(message: "Fake data not found")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Fake data")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        }

    }





}
```

I have the above code in order to access the worldweatheronline API. In the view controller, I take the value that the user inputs into a city and state field and pass that into getData as exampleDataNumber with a comma in between them and spaces removed with + (so austin,texas or san+francisco,california). This is based on code that my professor gave us for a separate example which worked but for some reason with this code, all that it will do is it will print the url but all of the other print statements that I put in to try and see the data as it gets passed through all aren't printing anything which is really confusing me because it seems like something should be printing. I do know that the API responds an HTTP instead of HTTPS but I added in the the App Transport Security Settings to my Info.plist to allow for insecureHTTPLoads (tried worldweatheronline.net and worldweatheronline.com). Is there anything else that I am missing?
[image]

Comment: Remember to never force unwrap your values either - is your app crashing at all because of this? Also, if you print the data just after `dataTask` what is returned? JSON?

Comment: The app isn't crashing it just prints the url and thats it

Comment: This is what is printed out when I print dataTask: LocalDataTask <CD7921F8-CD7C-4FA5-B5EF-2FCA1A6B9C59>.<1>

Comment: If this is your response from Data, and likewise jsonResult - need to check further up the chain

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, I think you just missed to call the `resume` method for the data task. Also, as you said, the ATS exception isn't necessary since the API uses https.  When you define `let datatask = ...` at the end just add `.resume()` to start the task right away.

Like this:

```
  class WeatherData {
     private let urlSession = URLSession.shared
     private let urlPathBase = "https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=efcc8b6300354517b08194421202604&format=json&q="

     private var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask? = nil

     var delegate:WeatherDataProtocol? = nil

     init() {
     }

     func getData(exampleDataNumber: String){

        var urlPath = self.urlPathBase
        urlPath = urlPath + exampleDataNumber

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        print(url!)

        let dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
           if error != nil {
              print(error!)
           } else {
              do {
                 let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                 if jsonResult != nil {
                    print(jsonResult)
                    let temperature_c = jsonResult?.value(forKeyPath: "data.current_condition.temp_C") as Any

                    if temperature_c != nil {
                       self.delegate?.responseDataHandler(data: jsonResult!)
                    } else {
                       self.delegate?.responseError(message: "Fake data not found")
                    }
                 } else {
                    print("Fake data")
                 }
              } catch {
                 print("Error")
              }
           }
        }.resume()
     }
  }
```

I created a tiny project to test it and looks fine:

[image: Request valid data number]

[image: Request blank data number]

If you want to play with the sample project you can download it from: https://github.com/acyrman/StackOverflow61449278

I had to create and implement `WeatherDataProtocol`, since you didn't share that code I create a very simple one in order to compile the project.

Comment: Nowadays is better to use strong types and take advantage of JSON Decoder. You can use a site like https://app.quicktype.io to generate Swift data structures code that represents the json response. With that code in your project you can decode the data like this: `let weatherInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDataStructure.self, from: data)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `let` from the declaration of `dataTask` in your function. You need to set the ivar so it has a strong reference while the `URLSession` executes.

Comment: I changed the let to var and it didn't change anything. Is that what you meant for me to do?

Comment: `URLSessionDataTask` works fine without a strong reference.